# Change Array Keys with a Map Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In the main `array`, I have:

```
 $array=array('index1'=>'value1', 'index2'=>'value2' , ....);
```

In another array, I keep the `key=>index` relationship:

```
$map=array('key1'=>'index1', 'key2'=>'index2' , ...);
```

Is there any simple way to combile these two array into one to get:

```
$combine=array('key1'=>'value1', 'key2'=>'value2', ...);
```

that is values from main array and keys comes from the map array.

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$array1=array('index1'=>'value1', 'index2'=>'value2');
$array2=array('key1'=>'index1', 'key2'=>'index2');

foreach($array2 as $key => $val){
    if(array_key_exists($val,$array1))
        $combined[$key] = $array1[$val];
}

// Output
print_r($combined);


?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the `$map` array and extract the value for `$array` accordingly and put them to the `$combine` array.  You can try this -

```
$array=array('index1'=>'value1', 'index2'=>'value2');
$map=array('key1'=>'index1', 'key2'=>'index2');

$combine = array();

foreach($map as $key => $val) {
    $combine[$key] = $array[$val];
}
var_dump($combine);
```

**Output**

```
array(2) {
  ["key1"]=>
  string(6) "value1"
  ["key2"]=>
  string(6) "value2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution here, if the keys and values already are in the expected order, and you are certain all arrays have the same length, use the [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) function together with `array_keys` and `array_values`

```
<?php
$array=array('index1'=>'value1', 'index2'=>'value2');
$map=array('key1'=>'index1', 'key2'=>'index2');

$combine = array_combine( array_keys($map), array_values($array) );

print_r($combine);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
)
```

Comment: Huff, good thing all keys are in the correct order, otherwise your entire code would break..

Comment: @Rizier123 > Yes, you are correct. The keys and values need to be in the correct order, as I stated in the answer - and also they need to be the same length, although PHP will return FALSE if they are not.

Answer (score 1):

Variant with no own code, only functions. It takes only keys presented in both arrays:

```
$array=array('index1'=>'value1', 'index2'=>'value2' , 'index3'=>'value3');
$map=array('key1'=>'index1', 'key2'=>'index2');

// next two lines if arrays may be of different length
$newmap = array_intersect_key(array_flip($map), $array);
$newarray = array_intersect_key($array, $newmap);

$new = array_combine($newmap, $newarray);
var_dump ($new);
```

output:

```
array(2) { ["key1"]=> string(6) "value1" ["key2"]=> string(6) "value2" }
```